# Laravel: Eager loading with 3 "relations"

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I've got an `Album` model. An `Album` can have many `Event` and many `Picture` but an `Event` belongs to one `Album` and one `Picture` belongs to one `Album` too.

I'm trying to make a list of events. In each event, I would like to display album's title and 3 random pictures from this album.

I think I have to use Eager Loading to do so but I'm a little bit confused. Currently I can have a list of albums and take 3 random pictures from them like this:

```php
$albums = Album::with(array('pictures' => function($query) {
    $query->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(2);
}))->get();

foreach ($albums as $album) {

    echo $album->title;

    foreach ($album->pictures as $picture) {

        echo $picture->filename;

    }

}
```

This is working but I have to start from events instead of albums. I don't know how to make all these relations work together. Event -> Album -> Pictures and display them into a view.

Comment: Have you tried something like $Event::with(['Album' => function($q)
{
    $q->with('Picture')->orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(2);
}]);

Comment: You can't use `take` on eager loaded query to load 2 pictures per album, it will limit all pictures to 2. Read this: http://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/

Comment: @cubiclewar unfortunately I get `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher::with()`
@JarekTkaczyk wow, it seems to be very painful ! All this code just to query on some relations ? Are you sure there's no simple way to do this ?

Comment: @Tkaczyk ah of course same behavior as limitTo()

Answer (score 1):

Then you need a `one-to-many` relationship and you need to create relationship methods for both sides, for example:

In `Event` model:

```
public function album()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Album', 'album_id');
}
```

In `Album` model:

```
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Event', 'album_id');
}

public function pictures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Picture', 'album_id');
}
```

So now you are able to start with `Event`, for example:

```
$events = Event::with('album.pictures')->get(); // or paginate(10), 10 per page
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I updated my code to work with your solution. But I still have a problem: when I do `$query->orderByRaw("RAND()")->take(2);` to show only 2 album pictures per event (like in my 1st post), I only get 2 pictures for ALL events. Only the last event in list will have it's 2 pictures, not the other ones...

Comment: Sorry! i didn't get what you asked for now, what it does now ?

Comment: Let's say that I have 3 events to display and I want to show 2 pictures per event. If I use `->take(2)` on the query like I said above, only one event will show the 2 pictures, the other ones are empty.